# How to validate client code has not been altered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

I am working on a client/server SDK project where the iOS client SDK is distributed to developers as code rather than a static library (we have business reasons for this distribution method). I have run across some situations where we suspect some developers are altering the client SDK code. I would like to update our client SDK to more proactively detect this.

An idea I have was to somehow checksum the code files when they compile, and have the client SDK report that checksum when it interacts with the server along with the SDK version. We would notate the checksum for each version on our side before we release the client SDK, and then reject anything sent to our server when the client SDK checksum isn't correct for their version.

I have a couple questions here:

1. How would I unobtrusively checksum the client SDK Objective-C code at compile time?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish my general goal?

Comment: More information about *why* you want to restrict this would be helpful if possible. This will enable us to effectively brainstorm, because the only answers you're going to get now are `no` without some help.

Comment: I care because because the SDK user has an incentive to alter the values that the SDK generates and reports to make the results more favorable to them. The reason we can't "close source" the SDK code is we want to allay any privacy concerns by showing all exactly what the SDK does.

Answer (score 3):

> How would I unobtrusively checksum the client SDK Objective-C code at compile time?

I don't think that's possible as you imagine/want it. If one has access to the source code, then he will be able to modify anything - including hardcoded checksums (and he can just patch out the checking code anyway).

> Is there a better way to accomplish my general goal?

Well... If you can't distribute your library as closed source, then no, not really... Maybe require in the license that the code not be modified, and block - using the server - those who, suspectedly, alter the code.

But nevertheless: why do you care about the modification of the code so much?

Comment: I care because because the SDK user has an incentive to alter the values that the SDK generates and reports to make the results more favorable to them. Good point about patching out the checksum.

Comment: @claireware That's not exactly your issue. If I write an app and completely disregard the results it returns and show something absolutely fake to the user, then I can do it even without altering a single source line of code in the library.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. One thing to note is that the SDK doesn't show anything to the app user.

Answer (score 0):

This approach offers a bit more security than nothing:

1. Add a build-rule that generates a cryptographic hash of the library source code at compile time, and build the result into the library.
2. Send the hash, along the library version number to the server.
3. Validate at the server that the hash and version numbers match at the server.

It's not safe against a determined attacker as they can simply build script for the library with a pre-computed hash of the unmodified version.   You can probably obfuscate the process to some extent.